# Angular Form Validation using div id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am struggling trying to release the Form Validation with this div. I get the Validation working on the div but once I enter data it should release the hold and set the model to IsInvalid false but it keeps it at true.

> is there anything else I need to do?

ts file

```
 initControlGroup(fb: FormBuilder) : FormGroup {
        var labelid = this.editorId;
        return fb.group({
            labelid: ["",Validators.required]        
        });
    }

onValueChange(model: SentencePartModelBase) {        
    this.modelchange.next(model);
}
```

html run time

```
<div id="descriptor-7c1f8c31-9327-a782-6653-6c29b3e7f279">1</div>
```

html

```
<Descriptor [model]="model" (modelchange)="onValueChange(model)"></Descriptor>
```

Also tried this same result

```
 initControlGroup(fb: FormBuilder) : FormGroup {
        var labelid = this.editorId;
        return fb.group({
            [labelid]: ["",Validators.required]        
        });
    }
```

Debugger displays value as empty string

```
descriptor-e614bca5-d7bc-e8e3-fb99-33b735fb830c: FormControl
asyncValidator: null
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
value: ""
```

Comment: I guess that's because you've coded `labledid:` instead of `[lablelid]:` meaning that you are using `labelid` as a text instead of taking it's value

Comment: @Sergey I get a runtime error using [lablelid]:

Comment: it's Angular? must be [ngModel] and (ngModelChange). Ah! you're using Template driven Form, nor ReactiveForm

Comment: @Eliseo Template driven Form

Comment: @Jefferson, https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel

Comment: @Eliseo is that ReactiveForm?

Comment: Is it a requirement to work from div to form? If that's not the case I would first create a form and then create as many "divs" as needed

Comment: @Sergey All the other fields validation are working fine in divs just this one is having problems.

Comment: Could you reproduce it on a StackBlitz or give as more code? These bits are too small to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly explain about FormControl and formGroup (I am not sure if can help)

In Angular we can have a FormControl

```
control:FormControl=new FormControl('value',Validators.required)
```

Or a FormGroup, that's a group of formControls

```
formgroup:FormGroup=new FormGroup(
{
     prop1:new FormControl('value of prop1",Validators.required),
     prop2:new FormControl('value of prop2",Validators.required)
})
```

You can use FormBuilder to create a FormControl, but is not necessary

```
formgroup:FormGroup=this.fb.group(
{
     prop1:['value of prop1",Validators.required],
     prop2:['value of prop2",Validators.required]
})
```

Well when we has a complex object, generally we make a function to create the formGroup. It's good has an interface to help us

```
export interface Imodel
{
    prop1:string;
    prop2:string;
}
createFormGroup(data:any):FormGroup{
    data = data || {} as Imodel;
    return new FormGroup(
    {
         prop1:new FormControl(data.prop1,Validators.required),
         prop2:new FormControl(data.prop2,Validators.required)
    })
}
//so we can do in ngOnInit or in subscribe of a service:
   this.formGroup=this.createFormGroup(null) //create an empty formGroup
   this.formGroup=this.createFormGroup(data) //create an formGroup with data
```

A FormControl or a formGroup exists independently we use input or not. We can see in html simply write (and it's a good idea to check our control/formGroup -see how we use the "safe operator"

```
{{control?.value}} - {{control?.valid}}
{{formGroup?.value|json}} - {{formGroup?.valid}}
```

How use this control in html?

```
<!--for the control-->
Control:<input [formControl]="control">
<div *ngIf="control?.invalid">Control invalid</div>
```

.

```
<!--for the formGroup-->
<!--I put a *ngIf to avoid errors when formGroup is null or undefined 
     (At very first of the application)-->
<div *ngIf="formGroup" formGroup="formGroup">
  <p>
    prop1:<input formControlName="prop1">
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.get('prop1')?.invalid">Prop1 required</div>
  </p>
  <p>
    prop2:<input formControlName="prop2">
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.get('prop2')?.invalid">Prop2 required</div>
  </p>
</div>
```

At last, when we're using FormControl of FormGroup, we can "listen" the changes in the own .ts (it's not necessary if we don't want to take an especial action, e.g. if only want to see some if is valid, we can use valid in the .html and it's not necessary). Always AFTER create the control/FormGroup

```
   this.formGroup=this.createFormGroup(null) //create an empty formGroup
   this.formGroup.get('prop1').valueChanges.subcribe(res=>{
           console.log(res)
   }
   //or 
   this.control.valueChanges.subcribe(res=>{
           console.log(res)
   }
```

See in the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) that valueChanges if a property of FormControl that is an Observable, so we can subscribe to this property

Comment: what is 'value of prop1' is that an object in the model?

Comment: We use a FormGroup if we can get an object. e.g. You want get {name:"Name",surname:"surname"} you use a FormGroup. Yes, it's true that you can want an object with a unique property {name:"Name"}. But in this last case.. why not simple get "Name"?. For this you can use a FormControl, not a FormGroup -a typical case is a input search-. I think an object like {prop1:"...",prop2:"..."}

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as a spelling error on lablelid?

this row:

```
[lablelid]: ["",Validators.required]
```

should be

```
[labelid]: ["",Validators.required]
```

Comment: Sorry I did see that and fixed it getting same result has before